# Volume of the body around z- axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F:=\left \{ (x,0,z) : x \geq 0, x^3 \leq z\leq 8\right \}$ and K is body, which is made by rotation of F around z - axis.

How can I calculate volume of K?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume can be divided into thin disks stacked along the $z-axis$.

For a given value of $z$, the radius of the disk will be $x=z^{\frac13}$. The thickness of a disk is $dz$.

Thus, the volume of the element is given by, $dV=\pi(z^{\frac13})^2dz$

Now, $z$ varies from $0$ to $8$. Thus, the total volume is given by

$$\int_0^8\pi z^{\frac23}dz=\frac35\pi z^{\frac53}=\frac35\pi.32=\frac{96}{5}\pi$$

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have one question: shouldn't we integrate from 0 to 2?

Comment: @Melina Why? We are dividing the volume into disks stacked along the $z-axis$, and the volume extends from $z=x^3$ to $z=8$. That is, at most it extends from $z=0$ to $z=8$. (when $x=0$).